# View data from a pivot table (Vertical mysql table)

Tags: php, mysql, pivot-table

I'm really confused with pivot tables, please see what I have and what I need to achieve:

**This is my mysql table structure**

```
id  meta_value            field_id   item_id

1   Ankur                 Fname      1
2   Gupta                 Lname      1
3   AAS Holdings          Company    1
4   Christie              Fname      2
5   Trojillo              Lname      2
6   AWS                   Company    2
7   Devadanam             Fname      3
8   Pulukuri              Lname      3
9   AAS Holdings          Company    3
10  Radha                 Fname      4
11  Neupane               Lname      4
......> There is no "Company" for that person
12  Marites               Fname      5
13  Torsar                Lname      5
14  AAS Holdings          Company    5
15  Muthanna              Fname      6
16  Shareef               Lname      6
17  GFTC                  Company    6
```

**I need to be able to present the data in HTML table using php mysql in that way**

```
First Name       Last Name       Company

Ankur            Gupta           ASS Holdings
Christie         Trojillo        AWS
```

And I also need to be able to sort that table by **Company** for example.

Here is what I tried to do but I know its totally wrong because the database could have only the Fname and Lname without the company which will cause to escape and use the next value and break the table and also the data could be stored in different order

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM system_frm_item_metas ORDER BY item_id";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

echo "<table><tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Company</th></tr>";
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   if ($row["field_id"] == "Fname") { echo "<tr><td>".$row["meta_value"]."</td>";}
   if ($row["field_id"] == "Lname") { echo "<td>".$row["meta_value"]."</td>";}
   if ($row["field_id"] == "Company") { echo "<td>".$row["meta_value"]."</td></tr>";}     
}
echo "</table>";
```

***Any help will be really appreciated***

Comment: What's the id column for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS eav_hell;

CREATE TABLE eav_hell
(entity INT NOT NULL
,attribute VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,value VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(entity,attribute)
);

INSERT INTO eav_hell VALUES
(1 ,'Fname','Ankur'),
(1 ,'Lname','Gupta'),
(1 ,'Company','AAS Holdings'),
(2 ,'Fname','Christie'),
(2 ,'Lname','Trojillo'),
(2 ,'Company','AWS'),
(3 ,'Fname','Devadanam'),
(3 ,'Lname','Pulukuri'),
(3 ,'Company','AAS Holdings'),
(4 ,'Fname','Radha'),
(4 ,'Lname','Neupane'),
(5 ,'Fname','Marites'),
(5 ,'Lname','Torsar'),
(5 ,'Company','AAS Holdings'),
(6 ,'Fname','Muthanna'),
(6 ,'Lname','Shareef'),
(6 ,'Company','GFTC');

SELECT entity
     , MAX(CASE WHEN attribute = 'Fname' THEN value END) Fname
     , MAX(CASE WHEN attribute = 'Lname' THEN value END) Lname
     , MAX(CASE WHEN attribute = 'Company' THEN value END) Company
  FROM eav_hell
 GROUP
    BY entity;

+--------+-----------+----------+--------------+
| entity | Fname     | Lname    | Company      |
+--------+-----------+----------+--------------+
|      1 | Ankur     | Gupta    | AAS Holdings |
|      2 | Christie  | Trojillo | AWS          |
|      3 | Devadanam | Pulukuri | AAS Holdings |
|      4 | Radha     | Neupane  | NULL         |
|      5 | Marites   | Torsar   | AAS Holdings |
|      6 | Muthanna  | Shareef  | GFTC         |
+--------+-----------+----------+--------------+
```

or (faster but less elegant)...

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.entity
              , f.value fname
              , l.value lname
              , c.value company
           FROM eav_hell e
           LEFT 
           JOIN eav_hell f
             ON f.entity = e.entity
            AND f.attribute = 'fname'
           LEFT 
           JOIN eav_hell l
             ON l.entity = e.entity
            AND l.attribute = 'lname'
           LEFT 
           JOIN eav_hell c
             ON c.entity = e.entity
            AND c.attribute = 'company';
```

Comment: That's great, another question please ... because I have a dynamic table .. it will keep showing NULL NULL NULL until it finds Fname Lname Company ... how can loop only if "Fname" is exist in the entity?

Or in  another way .. check the Fname value first and then group the entities

Comment: Lots of ways. E.g. Change the first LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN; add a WHERE clause to the end of the query. In fact, under these circumstances, you don't really need that first join at all. You can SELECT fname stuff from the `e` table instance.